# Render <li> tags if string is not null or not empty with Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor, umbraco

I want to display some li tags only if the strings received from the model contains text. Right now my list looks like this:

```
ul class="ul-with-bullets">
                @{
                    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        if (@Model.GetValue("punkt" + i) != "")
                        {
                            <li>@Model.GetValue("punkt" + i)</li>
                        }
                    }
                }
</ul>
```

The Model contains 5 properties (punkt1, punkt2, etc.), and I only want to display a li tag for these that contain a value (string). My above code still displays all the li tags on the page. I tried using string.Empty instead of "" as well but with the same result.

For reference, this is a partial view for the Archetype property editor in Umbraco. Each property in the fieldset is a textstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method

```
<ul class="ul-with-bullets">
     @{
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty( @Model.GetValue("punkt" + i)))
           {
              <li>@Model.GetValue("punkt" + i)</li>
           }
        }
      }
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool, dont forget to accept as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Will do in 7min :)